# Proving that $\gamma(ω^{β}n+η)=\gamma(ω^{β})+\omega^{β}(ω^{β}(n-1)+η)$, where $n∈ℕ$ , $η<\omega^{β}$ is not a successor ordinal, and $\beta>0$.

Tags: set-theory, alternative-proof, ordinals

Let $\gamma$ be the function which associates to each ordinal $\alpha$ the unique ordinal which is isomorphic to the well ordered set $\left(\alpha\times\alpha,\leq_{\text{c}}\right)$ (I have defined $\leq_{\text{c}}$ here [Finding an order isomorphism from $\text{On}\times\text{On}$ to $\text{On}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223194/finding-an-order-isomorphism-from-texton-times-texton-to-texton)). I want to show that

$$\gamma(\omega^{\beta}n+\eta)=\gamma(\omega^{\beta})+\omega^{\beta}(\omega^{\beta}(n-1)+\eta).$$

If I express $\omega^{\beta}n+\eta$ in its cantor normal form, then this can be done by using induction and the formula

$$\gamma(\omega^{\zeta_{0}}+\omega^{\zeta_{1}}m)=\gamma(\omega^{\zeta_{0}})+\omega^{\zeta_{0}+\zeta_{1}}m $$

(here $m\in\omega-\left\{ 0\right\}$, $\zeta_{0}\geq1$, and $0<\zeta_{1}\leq\zeta_{0}$)

But I want to prove this without using Cantor Normal Form. It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sup}{\operatorname{sup_{i<\xi}}}$

One can do this using induction and basic ordinal arithmetic only.

First lets observe a few rules:

1. $\gamma$ is continuous, that is whenever $\alpha$ is the limit of a sequence $(\alpha_i)_{i<\delta}$ then $\gamma(\alpha)=\operatorname{sup}_{i<\delta}\gamma(\alpha_i)$
2. $\gamma(\alpha+1)=\gamma(\alpha)+\alpha 2+1$

From 2. it follows by induction that $\gamma(\alpha+ n)=\gamma(\alpha)+\alpha 2n +1$ for infinite $\alpha$ and thus we get

3. $\gamma(\alpha+\omega)=\gamma(\alpha)+\alpha\omega$

Let $A(\beta,n,\eta)$ denote 
$$\gamma(\omega^\beta n+\eta)=\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta(n-1)+\eta)$$
for $\beta\geq 1, 1\leq n<\omega$ and $\eta<\omega^\beta$ not a successor.

In anything what follows, $\beta$ will always be $\geq 1$ and $n$ will be a positive integer and $\eta$ will be an ordinal which is not a successor.

First we will see

> If $A(\beta,n, 0)$ holds, then $A(\beta, n, \eta)$ holds for all non-successor $\eta\leq \omega^\beta$.

So assume $A(\beta, n, \eta)$ is true and $\eta<\omega^\beta$. We will show $A(\beta, n, \eta+\omega)$.

We have:
$$\gamma(\omega^\beta n+\eta+\omega)=\gamma(\omega^\beta n+\eta)+(\omega^\beta n+\eta)\omega=\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta(n-1)+\eta)+(\omega^\beta n+\eta)\omega$$
Since $\eta<\omega^\beta$, we can simplify the last term $(\omega^\beta n+\eta)\omega$ to  $\omega^\beta\omega$. Finally, 
$$ \gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta(n-1)+\eta)+\omega^\beta\omega=\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta(n-1)+\eta+\omega)$$

For the limit case, assume $\eta=\sup\eta_i$ for limit ordinals $\eta_i$ so that $A(\beta, n,\eta_i)$ holds for all $i<\xi$. Then by 1.:
$$\gamma(\omega^\beta n+ \eta)=\sup\gamma(\omega^\beta n+ \eta_i)=\sup\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta (n-1)+\eta_i)=\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta (n-1)+\eta)$$ 
To verify the last equality, note that $\sup\delta(\mu+\eta_i)=\sup\delta\mu+\delta\eta_i=\delta\mu+\delta\eta=\delta(\mu+\eta)$ for any choice of $\delta, \mu$.

Next up:

> If $A(\beta, n, 0)$ holds then $A(\beta, n+1, 0)$ does, too.

We already know that $A(\beta, n, \omega^\beta)$ is true. But this implies
$$\gamma(\omega^\beta (n+1))=\gamma(\omega^\beta n+\omega^\beta)=\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta(n-1)+\omega^\beta)=\gamma(\omega^\beta)+\omega^\beta(\omega^\beta n+ 0)$$
which is what we desire.

Note that proving $A(\beta, 1, 0)$ for any $\beta$ is trivial, as this amounts to $\gamma(\omega^\beta)=\gamma(\omega^\beta)$.

All in all, $A(\beta, n, \eta)$ holds for all appropriate $\beta, n, \eta$.

Comment: I am not sure how you wrote the non successor ordinal $\eta$ as a limit of a sequence of the smaller non-successor ordinals $\eta_{i}$ indexed by $\omega$. Is there a proof of this?

Comment: Good catch, the cofinality of $\eta$ will not always be $\omega$. However the proof works for any other cofinality.

Comment: @Eigenfield I changed it so that $\eta$ can have any cofinality

Comment: It’s not obvious to me that you can write any limit ordinal as the limit of a sequence of limit ordinals. Is there a general way of doing that?

Comment: This is not true. Thats why there is a successor step, "$A(\beta, n, \eta)$ implies $A(\beta, n, \eta+\omega)$" as $\eta+\omega$ is the next limit ordinal after $\eta$. Then there comes the limit case, where $\eta$ is limit, but not the next limit after any smaller limit. But that must mean that $\eta$ is the limit of limit ordinals.

Comment: You can also think about it in this way: Let $\langle \eta_\alpha\mid\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}\rangle$ be the increasing enumeration of all limit ordinals (and $0$). Then I show by induction on $\alpha$ that $A(\beta, n, \eta_\alpha)$ holds whenever $\eta_\alpha\leq\omega^\beta$. Now there is a successor case $\alpha=\alpha^\prime+1$ in which case $\eta_\alpha=\eta_\alpha^\prime+\omega$ and a limit case $\alpha=\operatorname{sup}_{i<\xi}\alpha_i$ in which case $\eta_\alpha=\operatorname{sup}_{i<\xi}\eta_{\alpha_i}$.

Comment: Yeah now that you mentioned you were enumerating the limit ordinals,  I understand your argument. By the way, is there a precise formula for $\eta_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @Eigenfield Great! I think $\eta_\alpha$ is just $\omega\alpha$.

Comment: @Eigenfield If there are no other uncertainies in my argument, would you please accept my answer?